# Geneos send email function with FKM

Tags: logging, monitoring, alerts, geneos, itrs

I'm using a FKM plugin in geneos to monitor log file for a keyword. How would I set up email alerting option if keyword is found?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to add an email alert. You will have to create an Action from options on left side on Gateway setup editor.

1. Select Action.
2. Click on New Action.
3. Select **sharedLibrary** under Options dropdown.
4. Enter **libemail.so** in Library file section.
5. Enter **SendMail** in Function name section.
6. Enter below static parameters. You need set appropriate values for below params.
   **a) _SMTP_SERVER
   b) _FROM
   c) _FROM_NAME
   d) _TO**

And in a Rule which gets fired when value changes in a column, call **run "email_action_name"**.